# Linux malloc return "real" memory

Tags: c, linux, malloc

In Linux, if you do `malloc` and do not use the memory, the memory is not "real".

This can can be easily tested if you do `malloc(some_really_big_number)`.

Then if the program begin to use the memory, Linux will begin to do real allocation and this can be seen in Linux process managers like `top` and if there is no enough memory, Linux will swap on disk.

Is there easy way to allocate and return real memory immediately after calling `malloc` (and if system begin to swap, malloc should wait for swap to be done)

## update

Tried following and it works:

- memset
- setting every 1024th byte to 0 - is faster than memset, but not too much
- setting every 4096th byte to 0 - same as previous

Tried following and it NOT works:

- calloc
- mlock - read about it somewhere in Stack Overflow
- setting last byte to 0

Comment: I haven't tried it, but what happens if you just use `calloc()`?

Comment: I believe that, instead of using `malloc`, you should be able to use `mmap` with `MAP_POPULATE` (in addition to other relevant flags).

Comment: works for me. will research it. memset with zero is also OK, except it took time

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt  I'm pretty sure I've seen at least one question and answer here documenting that `calloc()` on Linux is optimized to not actually have to set memory to zeros because the memory can be known to be newly-allocated and therefore already zero'd out.  Which means `calloc()` doesn't necessarily force the mappings to be created.  Now, if I could just find it...

Comment: @Nick Creating the mappings *will* take time no matter how or when they're done.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Creating mappings will take some time but not as much as a full `memset`.

Comment: Linux characterizes this behavior as a feature, not a bug.  Opinions on that do vary, but before you set out to work around it, you should consider whether it's a problem you actually need or want to solve.

Comment: Read about *memory overcommit*

Comment: @EricPostpischil Call `malloc()` for a large chunk of memory.  Time a `memset()` call.  Time a second `memset()` call.  The first call will take probably about an order of magnitude more time than the second one.  Maybe more if the system's virtual memory management is busy.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: So? How is a second `memset` taking longer than a second one relevant to whether a `memset` takes longer than merely creating the virtual memory mappings?

Comment: @dimich And then, if you care about reliability and availability, immediately disable it.  The delayed creation of the actual mappings when calling `malloc()` *et al* is not a feature of memory overcommit.  It's a feature of the copy-on-write nature of the VM system - pages aren't created until they're needed, such as when actually written to.  The *reservation* of that actual memory is what Linux lies about with its memory overcommit malfeature.  Kernel: "You know that memory I said you could use? **I LIED!!!! BWAAA HAAA HAAA!! OOM KILLER FOR YOU!!!  OR MAYBE YOUR MOST CRITICAL PROCESS!!!!**"

Comment: @EricPostpischil The **first** `memset()` taking a **lot** longer than the second for a newly-malloc'd block of memory is because the pages need to be mapped.  The fact that the second one is about an order of magnitude faster is because the bulk of the time was used by the actual mapping, not the memsetting.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't like the idea of memory overcommit too. Really reliable systems should not use dynamic memory allocations at all. But it's a trade between reliability, performance and ease of development. Besides, some tools like address sanitizer require overcommit to be enabled.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The delayed physical-to-virtual mapping is almost ubiquitous to Unix-type systems.  It's rarely a problem, but it can be.  Like when you try reading from a high-speed device that can generate multiple GBs of data every second into virtual memory that hasn't been mapped yet - I had fun explaining that to devs for a Solaris 8 system that was built around measly 900 MHz UltraSPARC III CPUs.  Those things absolutely would gag on the data if the buffers weren't actually forced to be mapped prior to use via `memset()` or other means.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The first `memset` call will take a lot longer than the second because the first has to actually read from and write to memory, whereas the second may be cached.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No. First, the memory didn't exist to be cached for the first run.  And when you're streaming through multiple GB of data, it won't fit into any cache anyway.  I've professionally run tests doing exactly this on instrumented systems where I could both count and time the mappings being done.  The performance killer here is the actual mapping of physical RAM to virtual memory, and on a machine that's busy the impact can be huge.  And if you're dealing with huge pages that need to be coalesced (Oracle DB...), that can freeze a server for multiple seconds at a time.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I confirm that a `memset` without prior memory mappings will take a while, longer than second `memset` (both larger than cache). However, from a subsequent experiment with a trivial system call repeated as many times as there are pages (and no memory writes being done), it appears the bulk of that time is due to the process being interrupted every page to do a single-page memory mapping. I do not have a Linux system to experiment on, and macOS does not appear to have MAP_POPULATE, but I suspect a complete MAP_POPULATE during `mmap` will be faster than mapping individual pages.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Indeed it will be faster - the mapping doesn't stall the user process over and over for each page in that case.

Comment: Is there any easier way to ask Linux to map the whole memory region?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, "It's rarely a problem, but it can be" was exactly my underlying point when I advised the OP "before you set out to work around it, you should consider whether it's a problem you actually need or want to solve."  Maybe it is indeed a problem they genuinely want (or need) to solve, but if not, then they are wasting time, effort, and lines of code.

Comment: If you don't want memory overcommit, disable it on your system. Disable swap too, because this "malloc should wait for swap to be done" is not doable if there is any swap at all. There is no function or system call or hack or workaround that would disable overcommit or swap for just this memory allocation.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit just one comment - if you disable swap, but leave overcommit on, linux still will behave the same